# Save files into deployed application folder with Openshift

Tags: java, deployment, openshift, war

I have an Java web application that uploads images and saves in a specific folder into main application folder:

```
- MyApplication
-- WEB-INF
-- META-INF
-- img_tmp
-- index.xhtml
...
```

My application saves images into img_tmp folder and the web pages get its. I'm using the getRealPath() method to get the root directory in local environment and it's working, but I've tried using the same method in Openshift environment and it doesn't work because I'm using WAR archives to deploy the application.

The question is: where Openshift unzips the WAR file and how can I access it? (OR) Is there an other way to deploy application in Openshift without using WAR files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In openshift you only can save files in a directory that is in an envirioment variable called $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
And you can acess this value by

```
System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR");
```

Heres a link to the openshift info about envirioment variables
https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#directory-variables

Hope that helps.